# Copy specific cells from a line and paste in another sheet, repeat on next line and repeat until cell in next line is blank

Tags: excel, vba

Edited: 2/2/19

I am still struggling to understand this. I have done a little more reading and realize that I was heading down the wrong path. I have created a better explanation of what I am trying to do and a sample below. I need your help me with Steps 1-2, Steps 4-5 and Steps 7-9. 
Thank you for your patience and understanding!

```
Sub Weeder_Repeater()
'
' 1) Copy Columns "D:L" Starting at Line 4 from Candidate Weeder sheet
' 2) Special Paste, Values, Transpose, to Metal Powder Bed AM Calculator sheet Cell "Q6"
' 3) Call Weeder_RAPID_Cal macro
' 4) Copy solution from Metal Powder Bed AM Calculator sheet Cell "Q15"
' 5) Special Paste, Values to Candidate Weeder sheet Column "O"
' 6) Call Weeder_RAPID_Reset macro
' 7) Move to next line in Candidate Weeder sheet
' 8) Repeat Steps 1-7
' 9) End when Blank in Column "D" encountered
'

'Step 1-2


'Step 3
    Call Weeder_RAPID_Calc

'Step 4-5


'Step 6
    Call Weeder_RAPID_Reset

'Step 7-9


End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use a for loop to determine when you need to end or you should look at using the END function from the range object which will ultimately give you the last cell and then you can copy in bulk. Also, using SELECT isn’t a great idea, you should reference the cell directly. There are a few things you should look at but I think you know that. :-)

Comment: Hi, why do you need to loop? Why not just copy the whole range at once? You only need to loop if there is some criteria to what you copy. If you just want to copy the used range, just find the last used row and copy the entire range at once. No need for a loop

Comment: @urdearboy read my comment again man. I gave 2 options, one of them being bulk copy.

Comment: @BradDixon why?

Comment: @urdearboy your comment seemed like it was referring to mine. My mistake if it wasn’t.

Comment: I am setting this up to go through thousands of Additive Manufactured part candidates that could be converted from traditionally manufactured methods. Most will not make the cut. After I copy and paste the information into the specific cells of the model, my model will automatically run the calculation and then my macro will pull the conclusion and paste it in the Data page, Reset the model and then move to the next line of the Data page which contains the next parts information. I want this to repeat each of the 30 steps over and over again until it reaches the end of the list of parts.

Answer (score 0):

'Specify Out-range Data

For counter = 3 To 10000

```
'Conditions that you can change it. in the bellow codes (counter) is your cell number and the number after comma is your column index. you can also do not specify your column and only loop through cells. you can also use from (i,j) for looping through both cells and columns (means two (For) loops).
```

If Worksheets("2nd QC").Cells(counter, 2).Value < Worksheets("2nd QC").Cells(counter, 3) _
   Or Worksheets("2nd QC").Cells(counter, 3).Value < Worksheets("2nd QC").Cells(counter, 4) _
   Or Worksheets("2nd QC").Cells(counter, 4).Value < Worksheets("2nd QC").Cells(counter, 5) Then

Worksheets("2nd QC").Rows(counter).Interior.Color = 65535

Else
   Worksheets("2nd QC").Cells(counter).Value = Worksheets("2nd QC").Cells(counter).Value

End If

Next counter

'Exit Loop Example:

Sub ExitStatementDemo()

Dim I, MyNum

```
Do                ' Set up infinite loop.

    For I = 1 To 1000    ' Loop 1000 times.

        MyNum = Int(Rnd * 1000)    ' Generate random numbers.

        Select Case MyNum    ' Evaluate random number.

            Case 7: Exit For    ' If 7, exit For...Next.
            Case 29: Exit Do    ' If 29, exit Do...Loop.
            Case 54: Exit Sub    ' If 54, exit Sub procedure.
        End Select
    Next I
Loop
```

End Sub

'I hope it help

Comment: I am not following, is the looping state "For counter =3 To 10000" and the statement "Next counter" that which stops it? Sorry I am a real novice at this. I have figured out how to copy and paste and the cells, I don't know how to tell it to go to the next line and repeat Step 1 after it gets to step 30.

Comment: use an "Exit For" statement as a condition for "else if" and explain if my conditions does not achieve exit from for loop; this is for stopping your loop. but for doing it after finish of 1st time looping, you have to use from a button to ignite it again (the faster and better way) or you have to add another for loop or do while as a upper loop (not recommended, make you macro so slow). any way, if you open view code in excel and press F1 button you will see many examples.

Comment: i described how to go to the next row with for loop and counter. please have another look on the my codes.

Comment: i also added and other example for you at the bottom of the previous sample codes. the last example is from the excel help that i have copied it for you.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I am still having trouble understanding and probably explaining what I am trying to do. I edited my question above and input a new script draft that I hope better explains what I am trying to do. Again, thank you for your input and patience with me on this. Patrick